# grouping based on time frequency and string column?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

I am trying to combine a set of strings based on the time and an ID, I want to group the data using a 5 minute interval from the first time occurance.

Data:

```
ID |   Q   | Timestamp       |
1  | a > b | 24/06/2017 18:11|
1  | b > b | 24/06/2017 18:12|
1  | b > c | 24/06/2017 18:13|
1  | c > d | 24/06/2017 18:14|
1  | c > e | 24/06/2017 18:17|
2  | a > b | 24/06/2017 18:12|
2  | b > c | 24/06/2017 18:15|
```

Desired Result:

```
ID |              Q               | Timestamp       |
1  | a > b > b > b > b > c > c > d| 24/06/2017 18:11|
1  | c > e                        | 24/06/2017 18:17|
2  | a > b > b > c                | 24/06/2017 18:12|
```

I am currently trying to use this:

```
grouped = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='5M'), 'ID']).agg(lambda x: '>'.join(set(x)))
```

However, its not quite there, this is breaking the timestamp and failing to join in time order. It appears to only do the first timeframe also.

Any help would be much appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

you are grouping with 5 month frequency:

`5M` = 5 months.

`5min` or `5T` = 5 minutes.

see this [time_aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)

if you will do it with `5T` frequency you will get results with minutes that can be equally divided by 5 (in this case starting at 18:10), for example:

```
ids = [*[1]*5, 2]
q = [f'{i:02}' for i in range(6)]
dates = pd.date_range('2017-06-24 18:11', periods=6, freq='1min')
df = pd.DataFrame({'ids':ids, 'q':q,'dates':dates,})
df
   ids   q               dates
0    1  00 2017-06-24 18:11:00
1    1  01 2017-06-24 18:12:00
2    1  02 2017-06-24 18:13:00
3    1  03 2017-06-24 18:14:00
4    1  04 2017-06-24 18:15:00
5    2  05 2017-06-24 18:16:00
```

grouping with 5 min frequency gives you this

```
grouped = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='dates',freq='5min'), 'ids']).agg(lambda x: '>'.join(set(x)))
grouped

                                   q
dates               ids             
2017-06-24 18:10:00 1    02>03>01>00
2017-06-24 18:15:00 1             04
                    2             05
```

if you want `18:11` to be your start date you can offset your data and then offset is back:

```
df['dates'] -= pd.offsets.Minute(1)
grouped = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='dates',freq='5min'), 'ids']).agg(lambda x: '>'.join(set(x))).reset_index()
grouped['dates'] += pd.offsets.Minute(1)
grouped

                dates  ids               q
0 2017-06-24 18:11:00    1  04>00>03>02>01
1 2017-06-24 18:16:00    2              05
```

thus achieving the desired result.

a more general answer is offsetting the minimum date to the nearest minute that can  equally divided by `n` (in your case `n=5` and the minimum is `18:11`) .